# How to draw a calculated line on quantmod chart

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to draw my own calculated indicator to the quantmod chart. For example: the average high of the last 6 days. Is there a way to draw such a series on the chart? I tried the following but without success.

```
SPY<-getSymbols("SPY", src = 'yahoo', from = '2007-01-01', auto.assign = FALSE)
SPY$Last6DaysHigh<-(Lag(SPY$SPY.Close,k=6)+Lag(SPY$SPY.Close,k=5)+
                    Lag(SPY$SPY.Close,k=4)+Lag(SPY$SPY.Close,k=3)+
                    Lag(SPY$SPY.Close,k=2)+Lag(SPY$SPY.Close,k=1))/6

Last6DaysHigh <- xts(!as.logical(SPY[,7]),index(SPY))
chart_Series(SPY,TA="add_TA(Last6DaysHigh,on=-1)")
```

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do. You say you're trying to plot the average of the high of the past 6 days, but your code attempts to plot a logical vector where all but one observation is false (i.e. a single point).

Comment: MY  bad, I took off the logical vector that you comment about.I can't operate my R session right now.I hope that removing the logical vector will solve the issue.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
library(quantmod)
SPY <- getSymbols("SPY", auto.assign = FALSE)
SPY$Last6DaysHigh <- rowMeans(Lag(Cl(SPY),k=1:6))
chart_Series(SPY,TA="add_TA(SPY$Last6DaysHigh,on=-1)")
```

I suspect the issue is related to the fact that your code attempts to plot a single point because it plots a logical vector where all but one observation is false.